# Why will my program not store the first user designated input?

Tags: c

I want the user to be able to enter 3 inputs.  The first and 3rd being numbers and the 2nd a symbol like +.  The 2nd and 3rd values will be stored but the 1st value will not be stored. Any Ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int min12;
    char opper;
    int x=0;
    int min13;

    printf("enter the integer number %d\n", x);
    scanf( "%d %s %d", &min12, &opper, &min13);
    printf("%d %s %d", min12, &opper, min13);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%s` is for a string, use `%c` for a single character.

Comment: And don't use `&` for the arguments in `printf()`.

Comment: try these : `scanf( "%d %c %d", &min12, &opper, &min13);` then enter the input like this : `1 + 2`

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't created a c program in a year, and lost all my examples and previous programs to go back to when my laptop failed.

Answer (score 0):

`opper` is a single `char`, a single character, but you're using `%s` which expects a `char *`, a string. You don't get a warning because `&opper` is a `char *`.

You're getting output like "0 + 5" because `scanf` is overwriting memory when it tries to write to `&opper`. `&opper` points to a single character, and `+` is a single character, so what's the problem?

The problem is C strings are terminated by a null byte. Strings always need one extra byte. So it tries to store `+\0`, two bytes. `opper` only has one byte of storage, so it overwrites the next hunk of memory which happens to be `min12`.

You can see this by printing out their pointers.

```
printf("opper: %p\n", &opper);
printf("min12: %p\n", &min12);

opper: 0x7fff5315f4b7
min12: 0x7fff5315f4b8
```

`min12` is immediately after `opper` in memory. So `scanf` writes a number to `min12`, then it writes one character to `opper`, and the null byte for the string spills over into `min12` causing its first byte to be 0.

Instead, use `%c` for a single character. You do pass in the address of `opper` to `scanf` because it needs to write to that memory, but you pass it by value into `printf` because printf only needs to read one byte.

```
scanf( "%d %c %d", &min12, &opper, &min13);
printf("%d %c %d", min12, opper, min13);
```

---

Because `min12` is 4 or 8 bytes, you can get some weird effects from zeroing out just the first byte that illustrate how numbers are stored.

```
enter the integer number 0
2147483647 + 5
2147483392 + 5
```

2147483647 is 0x7FFFFFFF which is the highest number you can safely store in a 32 bit signed integer. 2147483392 is 0x7FFFFF00 showing the byte that got zeroed.

But wait, didn't it zero the first byte of `min12`? Yes. Shouldn't it be 16777215? 0x00FFFFFF? No, not on my machine. This illustrates that [my x86 processor is little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), meaning the least significant byte is at the lowest memory slot. Basically, numbers are stored backwards from what you'd expect. It's like writing 2001 and saying that's "one thousand and two".